# "tkterminal who to use get_output"

Tags: python

I like get output of tkterminal but method .get_output() not work

My code is:

```
py_terminal = Terminal(background="black",foreground="white")
py_terminal.place(x=30,y=30)
py_terminal.run_command("ls")
py_terminal.get_output()
```

But send this error
AttributeError: 'Terminal' object has no attribute '_out'. Did you mean: '_root'?

How can I get the output?

Comment: Downvoted because: [Missing exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a threading issue.
As `Terminal.run_command` executes the given command in a different thread, `Terminal.get_output` will be called too early and won't have any output ready at that point (the variables get assigned when running the command) which causes `Terminal._out` to be unavailable.

`time.sleep` wouldn't work in this case, as `Terminal.run_command` requires interaction with a TK widget which seems to block further execution till it is ready to handle these.

This means, that first `tkinter.Tk.mainloop` has to be called to make the widget available and responsive to the used TK commands and therefore produce any kind of output.

Comment: Ok i will try add button and execute de terminal.get_out()